# Python regex on on excluding same combination

Tags: python, regex

Below is the string I wanted to select only word followed by digit OR digit followed by word `ab8efc05ee6105461869578b9ff0ee0048f37413340ec3ca3c924590c60b8ff2` except `last12` and `Stmnt_052015_6043`

Used Regex:`\w?\d\w+|\w+\d+\w+=+|\w+\d+\w+`, but it is even selecting the `last12` and `Stmnt_052015_6043`.

> /ggg-web/ggg/ab8efc05ee6105461869578b9ff0ee0048f37413340ec3ca3c924590c60b8ff2/statements/monthly/last12/ab8efc05ee6105461869578b9ff0ee0048f37413340ec3ca3c924590c60b8ff2/save/Stmnt_052015_6043

Need regex pattern to select the following string in the above-mentioned string

> ab8efc05ee6105461869578b9ff0ee0048f37413340ec3ca3c924590c60b8ff2

Greatly appreciates the solution.

Comment: what you want to select always starts with `ab`?

Comment: Can you post your expected output please?..I mean..what you want to get from your provided example at the end?

Comment: Please clarify more, I'm not really sure what you want to match.

Comment: o/p should as below...

Comment: Actually need to mask the values in the place of *  below using other thru regex /ggg-web/ggg/*/last12/*/save/Stmnt_052015_6043

Comment: It's unclear what you want...Please edit your question and post your input and what is your expected output...

Comment: In my regex pattern tried not to select last12 and Stmnt_052015_6043,it is not happening.

Comment: Are you trying to extract these strings: `ab8efc05ee6105461869578b9ff0ee0048f37413340ec3ca3c924590c60b8ff2` ?...is that what you want to get as output?

Comment: @sdv, alright, I saw your updated Question, now tell me, is the strings you need (`ab8efc05ee6105461869578b9ff0ee0048f37413340ec3ca3c924590c60b8ff2`) always in this format, I mean always similar like that or it can be other format?

Comment: Yes,need to select only similar format

Comment: What I mean i..I see the strings you are looking for are exactly the same...right?

Answer (score 0):

I will give couple of solutions that might work for you, see which one fits your needs:

Solution -1 :

If you have these two strings before your targets (`ggg` & `last12`), then:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?<=ggg/|last12/)(\w+)', re.DOTALL)
test_str = "/ggg-web/ggg/ab8efc05ee6105461869578b9ff0ee0048f37413340ec3ca3c924590c60b8ff2/statements/monthly/last12/ab8efc05ee6105461869578b9ff0ee0048f37413340ec3ca3c924590c60b8ff2/save/Stmnt_052015_6043"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

[DEMO HERE](https://regex101.com/r/iA5gX2/4)

Solution - 2:

If different strings precedes your targets but your target strings always start with `ab` then this is more general:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'/(ab\w+)/', re.DOTALL)
test_str = "/ggg-web/ggg/ab8efc05ee6105461869578b9ff0ee0048f37413340ec3ca3c924590c60b8ff2/statements/monthly/last12/ab8efc05ee6105461869578b9ff0ee0048f37413340ec3ca3c924590c60b8ff2/save/Stmnt_052015_6043"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

[DEMO HERE](https://regex101.com/r/iA5gX2/3)

Comment: (?<=ggg/|last12/)(\w+),This option works.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @sdv , good for you...if you are satisfied with the answer, Please do accept it as answer to your Question...